# Swift - pass data from tableview to third viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have too much code to paste it all in, so I'm going to be vague. I think I just need a general idea of what to do, and then I'll be able to do it.

I have a beautiful table built with a list of local businesses. When you click on one, it opens up the DetailView, with some great information about the business. I have a MAP button on the DetailView that triggers Thirdview with a Mapview inside of it.

I'm having issues retrieving data from the cells in the TableView in the Thirdview.

My views:

Tableview => DetailView => Thirdview

In my Thirdview, can I call the information from Tableview?

Or is it easier to pass the information from DetailView to Thirdview?

Thanks!

Comment: I would pass the data in to the detail view, then in `prepareForSegue`, pass the data to the third view.

Comment: Got it. So prepareForSegue is the best bet. 

I guess then I need to figure out what to put inside the prepareForSegue. Any suggestions? @dstepan

Comment: I'll post an answer which should work it out for you.

Comment: see my answer below. If the data is always going to be the same, you could also create a singleton, but that may not be best for your approach.

Comment: That depends on the derived data, if there is data in tableView controller that need to be displayed in the third viewController without the need to be in the second viewController, there is no need to let the second (details viewController) to hold it. there are several approaches to achieve this, delegation might be a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableView

```
var objects: [MyObject] = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let myObject = objects[indexPath.row]

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any) {

    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {

        let detailVC = segue.destination as! MyDetailVC

        detailVC.dataFromTableView = myObject

    }

}
```

Detail View

```
var dataFromTableView = MyObject()

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any) {

    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {

        let thirdVC = segue.destination as! MyThirdViewController

        thirdVC.dataFromDetailView = dataFromTableView

    }

}
```

Third View

```
var dataFromDetailView = MyObject()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    print(dataFromDetailView)

}
```

Comment: You are AWESOME. This definitely worked once I figured out how to translate all of you variables to mine :) @dstepan